# iOS 12 FCM Push Notification not received

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Device has iOS 12 or iOS 11. Sometimes they get FCM Push Notification, but sometimes they did not get FCM Push Notification continuously.

When one uninstalled and install app again and getting new device/fcm token, they are starting to get FCM Push Notification. No any single change in code.

I do not know what is a problem in code?
Can anyone help me about this issue and why user are getting notification after reinstall app again?

My code configuration

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        [FIRApp configure];

            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
                UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
                UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
                | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
                | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
                [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                }];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

            [FIRMessaging messaging].delegate = self;
            UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

                if (localNotif)
                {
                    NSUserDefaults *userDefaultLocalNotif = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [userDefaultLocalNotif setObject:localNotif forKey:@"localNotif"];
                    [userDefaultLocalNotif synchronize];
                }

        return TRUE;

        }


        - (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken 
{

        NSLog(@"FCM registration token 1: %@", fcmToken);

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        //NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
        //NSLog(@"deviceTokenString : %@",deviceTokenString);

        [FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;

        //NSLog(@"FCM registration token 2: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

    }


    // [START receive_message]
    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
    {

        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
        /*
         // Print message ID.
         if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
         NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
         }
         */
        // Print full message.
        NSLog(@"Userinfo didReceiveRemoteNotification 1 %@",userInfo);


    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler 
{
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

        /*
         // Print message ID.
         if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
         NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
         }
         */
        // Print full message.

        NSLog(@"Userinfo didReceiveRemoteNotification 2 %@",userInfo);

        [self getPushNotificationDetails:userInfo];

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    // [START ios_10_message_handling]
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    //#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    // Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.

    -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{

        //Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
        NSLog(@"Userinfo willPresentNotification%@",notification.request.content.userInfo);

        // Print message ID.
        /*
         NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
         if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
         NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
         }
         */

        // PSM Anks use when we want to redirect user to Notification page when app is open and user on any view of application
        //[self getPushNotificationDetails:notification.request.content.userInfo];

        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);

    }

    -(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{

        //Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
        NSLog(@"Userinfo didReceiveNotificationResponse%@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);

        // Print message ID.
        /*
         NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
         if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
         NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
         }
         */

        [self getPushNotificationDetails:response.notification.request.content.userInfo];
    }
```